# how to set text, focus, error on editText in android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I searched heavily on internet about how can i use `setFocusable()`, `setText()`, `setError()` etc etc methods on `editText(s)` in android with Kotlin (I know the fact that we can use the above mentioned methods in java) but I was not able to find the exact solution that will work for me.

I am using 
1.) Volley for http calls
2.) kotlin plugin for android studio with version = '1.1.3-2'
3.) anko library

> Problems that i am facing when app is running :
>   1.)The setError() method is not getting called.
>   2.)i am not able to use setText() and setFocus() on editText.

please note that I need the solution(s) in Kotlin not Java.

Thanks in advance!

```
private fun askAppointment() {

    if (editTextPersonName?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonName?.error ="Person Name cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextPersonMobile?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonMobile?.error = "Person Mobile cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextPersonEmail?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonEmail?.error = "Person Email cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextSubject?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextSubject?.error = "Subject cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextDescription?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextDescription?.error = "Description cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextAppointmentDate?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextAppointmentDate?.error = "Appointment Date cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextAppointmentTime?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextAppointmentTime?.error = "Appointment Time cannot be empty."
        return
    }
```

Comment: Please keep your code small. It's not clear where you have the problem so just add the necessary code with the containing problem.

Comment: @guenhter can u tell me how can i use  setFocus(), setText() on editText in android with KOTLIN...n also setError()

Comment: No, I'm not into android and can not give you advice, but if you make a better description (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) the chance is higher that anyone helps you and not just downrates your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simple. Lets suppose `etEmail` is the `EditText`. You can set text like this

```
etEmail?.setText("some text")
```

And for error you can use this

```
etEmail?.error = "This is error"
```

And for set foucus you can try this one but i am not sure about it.

```
etEmail?.isFocusable = false
```

I hope this will help you.

Check the working screenshot of above code.

[image]

use this logic in `askAppointment()`

```
private fun askAppointment() {

    if (editTextPersonName?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonName?.error = "Person Name cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextPersonMobile?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonMobile?.error = "Person Mobile cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextPersonEmail?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextPersonEmail?.error = "Person Email cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextSubject?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextSubject?.error = "Subject cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextDescription?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextDescription?.error = "Description cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextAppointmentDate?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextAppointmentDate?.error = "Appointment Date cannot be empty."
        return
    } else if (editTextAppointmentTime?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        editTextAppointmentTime?.error = "Appointment Time cannot be empty."
        return
    } else {
        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    try {
                        val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
                        val feedback = jsonObject.getString("response")
                        toast("$feedback")
                        //finish()       //finish Activity after sending request
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                object : Response.ErrorListener {
                    override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                        toast("error :(")
                    }
                }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("personName", editTextPersonName?.text.toString())
                params.put("personMobile", editTextPersonMobile?.text.toString())
                params.put("personEmail", editTextPersonEmail?.text.toString())
                params.put("subject", editTextSubject?.text.toString())
                params.put("description", editTextDescription?.text.toString())
                params.put("appointMentDate", editTextAppointmentDate?.text.toString())
                params.put("appointMentTime", editTextAppointmentTime?.text.toString())
                return params
            }
        }

        //adding request to queue
        AppController.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: etEmail?.isFocusable = false is working fine but the other two methods are not working.

Comment: I just tested these in my project and these are working fine.

Comment: i've attached the screen shot you can check it out. There must be something that you're not doing right in your code. Can you post related code.

Comment: i am doing something like this `if (editTextPersonName?.text.toString() == "") {
            editTextPersonName?.error = "Person Name cannot be empty."
            return
        }`

Comment: your check is wrong.  ```if(etEmail?.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
                etEmail?.setError("Some error")
            }``` use this one

Comment: i'm directly getting response from server....it's not checking the if-elseif block

Comment: problem is with your if-else logic. see updated answer. Please do accept my answer since i have answered mentioned question in post. For more problem create another question

Comment: can u send me the code that u have written on this mail id : suhas07wagre@gmail.com

Comment: The amount of time i spent pulling my hair out until this shows me i just need a ? in there! ffs